# Set user context for development environment

Tags: authentication, .net-core

We are using OAuth 2.0 on production and integration stage. But on our development server we don't use authentication. Maybe it would be worthwhile to set it up at some point, but the effort would be too great at the moment...

Instead we use a dummy user. I'm rewriting an .Net 4 app in .Net Core and my approach to set the dummy user is the following. It works fine and that's the only code I had to adjust. All controllers etc. work without adjustment.

```
public class AuthNDeveloperMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthNDeveloperMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("sub", "Developer"),
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "NoAuthenticationTechnicalUser");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        httpContext.User = user;
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

and in Programm.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<AuthNDeveloperMiddleware>();
```

I'm just wondering is there a better way?

Controller use the following method to get the user (same for all stages)

```
public static class ControllerBaseExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserId(this ControllerBase controllerBase)
    {
        var userId = controllerBase.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub")?.Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            throw new Exception("User id not found");
        }
        return userId;
    }
}
```